# How to add answer specific feedback to dist3.Rmd?

Tags: r, moodle, r-exams

I'm looking at the `dist3.Rmd` example template from here: http://www.R-exams.org/templates/dist3/. The solution markdown is the general feedback provided after submission. I want to create feedback.

````
Solution
========
The distance $d$ of $p$ and $q$ is given by
$d^2 = (p_1 - q_1)^2 + (p_2 - q_2)^2$ (Pythagorean formula).

Hence $d = \sqrt{(p_1 - q_1)^2 + (p_2 - q_2)^2} =
  \sqrt{(`r p[1]` - `r q[1]`)^2 + (`r p[2]` - `r q[2]`)^2}
   = `r round(sol, digits = 3)`$.
\
```{r distplot, echo = FALSE, results = "hide", fig.path = "", fig.cap = ""}
par(mar = c(4, 4, 1, 1))
plot(0, type = "n", xlim = c(0, 6), ylim = c(0, 6), xlab = "x", ylab = "y")
grid(col = "slategray")
points(rbind(p, q), pch = 19)
text(rbind(p, q), c("p", "q"), pos = c(2, 4))
lines(rbind(p, q))
lines(c(p[1], p[1], q[1]), c(p[2], q[2], q[2]), lty = 2)
```
````

If the answer choice is correct, I'd like the general feedback to popup and if the answer is wrong, I'd like for the pythagorean formula and the image prompt to show up but not the calculation. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your jargon about "general feedback" I assume this is related to Moodle and the `exams2moodle()` interface in R/exams.

I tried to find out whether the feature you describe can be specified using [Moodle XML format](https://docs.moodle.org/39/en/Moodle_XML_format) but was not successful. So at the moment this is certainly not possible in R/exams and I'm not sure whether it would be possible in Moodle XML. If anyone is aware of a solution in Moodle XML, I would be interested and could check whether it would be possible to add this to `exams2moodle()`.

**Update:** Following the discussion in the comments with @ArvindMurali I briefly discuss here how it is possible to include images in the specific feedback from the "solution list". However, I still don't see how to separate specific and general feedback between different iterations of answering the question.

If you make a copy of `dist3.Rmd` to, say, `dist4.Rmd` you just need to modify two lines. In the options for the `r distplot` code chunk in line 35, add `fig.show = "hide"`. And in the `r solutionlist` chunk in line 46 replace the `answerlist(...)` command with:

```
answerlist(ifelse(sc$solutions,
  "This is correct!",
  "This is not correct, please consider: <br/> ![](distplot-1.png)"),
  markup = "markdown")
```

For preparing this for Moodle you then need to use `pluginfile = FALSE` so that the image is really embedded directly into the specific feedback (rather than via Moodle's plugin file declaration).

```
set.seed(1)
exams2moodle("dist4.Rmd", pluginfile = FALSE)
```

Then, the specific feedback for each incorrect item will display the plot from the `r distplot` chunk.

[image: dist4-moodle]

The formatting is not great but it works - so far so good.

The problem is that in addition to this specific feedback, the general feedback will also be displayed at the end - always, as far as I can see. If there were a way to delay this in Moodle, then I could check whether it is possible to interface this in R/exams.

Comment: Oh yeah! I forgot to mention that. Yes. This is with moodle. The solution typically is mapped to general feedback. Looked like using an explanations array would work for specific feedback for true and false options but I wasn't able to implement adding a figure to that array.

Comment: You mean putting images into the "Answerlist" in the "Solution" in an R/exams exercise? I got this to work when using `pluginfile = FALSE` in `exams2moodle()`, i.e., when embedding the base64 encoding directly into the feedback. The rendering in Moodle is then not great but the image is displayed.

Comment: I don't mean answers should have images. I mean the answer feedback should have image. The example code for dist3 creates a graph of the random points in Cartesian coordinates when the quiz is submitted in moodle. I would like to have that image displayed every time an answer choice is clicked and submitted, the image to be displayed along with whether the answer was right or wrong.

Comment: Yes, that was also what I was referring to. In R/exams the answer _options_ are the answerlist in the question and the corresponding _feedback_ is the answerlist in the solution. I now updated my response to show a worked example how the latter can embed images with the `pluginfile = FALSE` approach. The problem that remains is the separation of specific and general feedback that I don't know how to do in Moodle.